# Should I reuse a single WebView2 environment for multiple webview instances?

Tags: winapi, webview2

I have implemented a WebView2 component in our software, using C++/Win32. There can be multiple of these webviews. Should I create a new WebView2 environment for each one, or reuse it?

Currently I'm making a new environment for each view (using CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions). It "seems" fine, but I wondered if it wastes resources e.g extra browser processes. I couldn't find any guidance in the help.

Edit to clarify: the data folder for all of the webviews will be the same.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but are you sure you're using [C++/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwin32) (as opposed to, say, [C++/WinRT](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/))?

Comment: Definitely not using WinRT. I'm using this API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/?view=webview2-1.0.1264.42 with Windows Runtime Library (wrl.h) for the COM layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create multiple CoreWebView2Environment objects with the same parameters, they are all connected to the same user data folder, browser process, and other associated renderer and utility processes. You can create webview2s from any of those CoreWebView2Environment objects to get the same result. If you have a CoreWebView2Environment with different parameters (a different user data folder specifically) it will be connected to the different user data folder, a different browser process, and different other associated renderer and utility processes.

You can read more about the [WebView2 process model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/process-model?tabs=csharp).

Comment: Thanks! I find it hard to get your interpretation from the docs you reference :) It's kind of implied, but never said outright. Indeed, from another part, it seems like I definitely should NOT be creating multiple environments: "Each CoreWebView2Environment object needs to be configured with a different user data folder value.". I'm not doing that now, and it appears to work, so your explanation is plausible but not officially stated?

Comment: So ... can you point to something that says multiple environments will share everything if they have the same parameters?

Comment: I'll try to update the docs to be clearer. But in the interim, the docs do say that the user data folder can have only one browser process and vice versa. "All processes in a WebView2 Runtime processes collection are tied to the browser process, which in turn is associated with a single user data folder." So you cannot have more than one browser process (and associated renderer and other utility processes) for a single user data folder.

Comment: Ah sorry I hadn't picked up you're actually on the edge team, not trying to interpret things from outside like me :) OK, so the behaviour I'm seeing is OK, I'm not doing anything wrong having multiple environments?

Comment: ie. It seems like sharing a single CoreWebView2Environment would just be a nice to have

Comment: Yes no problem with either. You can use one CoreWebView2Environment and create all of your webview2s off of that, or you can create a new CoreWebView2Environment whenever you need to create a webview2. Just whatever works better for you.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate you direct answer on SO.

Comment: Thoughts: as a user of the APIs, the process model is sort of interesting, but I just want to know the correct way to use the API, and don't really care about the processes that may get launched. Indeed it should be transparent to me. So all I was really looking for was a pretty prescriptive comment in the APIs say "create one webview environment in your app" or "you can create as many webview environments as you want; data, processes and folders will be shared if the environments use the same settings,